# Access Call Graph of Simulator or Trace Simulator

Tags: q#

Is there a way to access the call graph of the simulator / trace simulator? It would be nice to be able to pull a complete list of the gates applied to each qubit, in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific API for this, but it should be straightforward to add hooks to the simulator. Source code is now available at https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-runtime.

There are two approaches you could take:

- Modify the operation implementations to log the gate and qubit ID each time they get called.
- Add a handler for the `onOperationStart` event in `SimulatorBase` that looks for the gates your interested in and logs the gate and qubit ID.

The first is probably more tedious, but simpler. If you use the second approach, the `ICallable.Name` property will be helpful.